# JLayeredPane doesn't show canvas layer below a transparent JButton layer

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jlayeredpane

I have a JLayeredPane with two layers. The bottom layer is a canvas with bounds (0, 0, 600, 400) and the top layer is a JButton with bounds (500, 300, 40, 40). The JButton is completely tansparent. So in this JButton area the canvas should be visible. But instead there is a white rectangle. It doesn't matter for the issue what is drawn on the canvas or if it is a canvas at all.

Here is the code:

```
public class Main extends JFrame {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private final Canvas canvas;
    private final JButton button;
    
    Main() {
        super("InvisibleButton");
        
        this.canvas = new Canvas();
        this.canvas.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 400);
        this.canvas.requestFocus();
        this.canvas.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        this.canvas.setVisible(true);
        
        this.button = new JButton();
        this.button.setBounds(500, 300, 40, 40);
        
        // Doesn't work
        this.button.setOpaque(false);
        this.button.setBorderPainted(false);
        this.button.setFocusPainted(false);
        this.button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
                
        this.button.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Dragged");
            }
            
        });
        
        JLayeredPane jlp = new JLayeredPane();
        jlp.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 400);
        jlp.add(this.button);
        jlp.add(this.canvas);
        
        this.add(jlp);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setSize(600, 400);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setVisible(true);
        
        Timer repainter = new Timer();
        repainter.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)canvas.getGraphics();
                
                Shape s = new Rectangle.Double(0, 0, 600, 400);
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g2d.fill(s);
                g2d.draw(s);
            }
            
        }, 0, 100);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

}
```

The drag event works great. But there is this white rectangle:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1CkL.png)

Comment: Why are you working with an invisible button?

Comment: 1) mixing AWT and Swing does not give the best results: try a `JPanel` instead of `Canvas`; 2) (standard warning) using `null` layout is most often not recommended; 3) not sure what the `TimerTask` is doing (does not seem like something standard like intended by Swing developers)

Comment: The button should represent the center of a kind of joystick. I wanted to put a picture with a circle on it (transprarance around the circle). After you have pressed the mouse on the center of the circle, i.e. on the button, you can then drag the circle back and forth within a larger circle. It is certainly also possible to move the whole button, but then the button would still have to be transparent around the circle and let the lower layer shine through.

Comment: So all you need is a component to display a semitransparent image and attach a mouselistener/mousemotionlistener to it. Use JComponent or JLabel. IIRC I once also had problems with transparent buttons.

Comment: I use the TimerTask in my other application to render all the stuff. There I need to update the stuff in regular time steps. The code above is only example code. But yes, of course, to show the issue the timer isn't necessary.

Comment: I just tried to use a JLabel with the semitransparent image. The JLabel is transparent by default. But it didn't change anything. The transparent parts are still colored white. In response to @user16320675 : Instead, using JPanel results in the above layer no longer being visible when repainting with the timer.

Comment: Thank you! I have just found the solution. I use a JPanel, then I put an empty JLabel with a small size over it, as with the button. The label is invisible and the MouseEvent is only triggered at this point. Perfect.

Comment: Don’t use `java.util.Timer`. When updating UI, use [`javax.swing.Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html). When truly needing timed background processing, use a `ScheduledExecutorService`. But in your case, it obviously should be a Swing timer.